# What is the difference between Connection from DataSource getconnection() and Mysql session?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I wonder if each time I get a connection from a DataSource with ds.getConnection() a new session between my application and MySQL instance is create or there is some reusing logic ?

Comment: It depends on how you configure the datasource. If you configure it to be a pooled datasource, you'll open N sessions and then reuse connections.

Comment: @BackSlash What I want to know is if the following is true: 1 connection = 1 session ?

Comment: Each connection uses a single session, however, closing a connection does not necessarily mean that the session is also closed. See the comment made by @BackSlash regarding the pooling.

Comment: So, if the mysql server is configured to have 50 sessions, then your application can have 50 connections in parallel.

Comment: @Shadow Can you answer the question with providing a link to where this is documented ?

Comment: @Shadow MySQL isn't configured with a maximum number of sessions. It is configured with a maximum number of connections.

Comment: @EJP I used the wording of the OP. In my detailed answer below I used maximum connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Connection object created by a DataSource represents a connection to a database - a session in a database, that is.

The maximum number of connections a database is configured to support limits the number of active Connection objects an application may have open simultaniously to the database.

However, if connection pooling is supported by a driver and is used in the code, then closing a Connection object in the code only returns the Connection object to the pool and the connection to the database itself is not closed. Connection objects within the connection pool can be reused in the code later without the need of creating a new connection to the database.

Pls see Java documentation on [DataSource object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html) for details.